# How to restart Resque workers automatically when Redis server restarts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque, rails-activejob

I have a Rails application that runs jobs on the background using the Resque adapter. I have noticed that once a couple of days my workers disappear (just stop), my jobs get stuck in the queue, and I have to restart the workers anew every time they stop.

I check using `ps -e -o pid,command | grep [r]esque` and launch workers in the background using 
`(RAILS_ENV=production PIDFILE=./resque.pid BACKGROUND=yes bundle exec rake resque:workers  QUEUE='*' COUNT='12') 2>&1 | tee -a log/resque.log`.

Then I stopped redis-server using `/etc/init.d/redis-server stop` and again checked the worker processes. They disappeared.

This gives a reason to think that worker processes stop maybe because the redis server restarting because of some reason.

Is there any Rails/Ruby way solution to this problem? What comes to my mind is writing a simple Ruby code that would watch the worker processes with the period, say, 5 seconds, and restart them if they stop.

**UPDATE:**
I don't want to use tools such as Monit, God, eye, and etc. They are not reliable. Then I will need to watch them too. Something like to install God to manage Resque workers, then install Monit to watch God, ...

**UPDTAE**
This is what I am using and it is really working. I manually stoped redis-server and then started it again. This script successfully launched the workers.

```
require 'logger'

module Watch

  def self.workers_dead?
   processes = `ps -e -o pid,command | grep [r]esque`
   return true if processes.empty?
   false
  end

  def self.check(time_interval)
   logger = Logger.new('watch.log', 'daily')
   logger.info("Starting watch")

   while(true) do
     if workers_dead?
       logger.warn("Workers are dead")
       restart_workers(logger)
     end
     sleep(time_interval)
   end
  end

  def self.restart_workers(logger)
   logger.info("Restarting workers...")
   `cd /var/www/agts-api && (RAILS_ENV=production PIDFILE=./resque.pid BACKGROUND=yes rake resque:workers QUEUE='*' COUNT='12') 2>&1 | tee -a log/resque.log`
  end

end

Process.daemon(true,true)
pid_file = File.dirname(__FILE__) + "#{__FILE__}.pid"
File.open(pid_file, 'w') { |f| f.write Process.pid }
Watch.check 10
```

Comment: This sounds like something I'd use [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) for

Comment: I'd check the logs (`log/resque.log`) and see what the problem is, or you can start the resque worker in the foreground for debugging purposes.

To run a queueing system like resque I'd setup a process management tool, like one of those: https://github.com/kostya/eye, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples

Comment: You can use process monitoring tools such as monit, god, eye etc. Personally I use eye gem.

Comment: @siegy22 I have rake redirect output into `log/resque.log` so, of course, I did have a look into this file hoping it will have something useful to find out why the workers stop. Unfortunately it has a couple of lines which give no clue about why workers stop. As for the the management tools, I don't like this idea. They add extra complexity and there is no guarantee they will not constantly crash themselves, or work properly.

Comment: @tirdadc  I am well aware of such tool like Monit, God, and etc. I don't like adding too much complexities to the project simply just to automatically restart workers when they stop. They are not reliable in production mode because of possible bugs or inconstancies with OS.

Comment: Of course your resque worker will crash when you shut down redis, why would you do that? The "use a process monitoring"-answer is just a workaround if your redis unexpectedly restarts, which shouldn't happen?

Comment: @siegy22 I don't do that myself. The redis possibly stop/restarts itself. I had a look at log files it restared several times.

Comment: My attempt would be fixing that, find out why it's restarting, when it doesn't restart anymore, resque should work without crashing

Comment: @siegy22 Agree. I made some fixes to redis config, now it works without problem. But I need such guard to make sure workers are always alive. I also constantly check logs.

Comment: I strongly recommend using systemd if you're on linux, it's easier to handle autostart for example. I've used eye in the past few years and it always served me well, it's super easy to configure as it's just plain ol' ruby

Comment: @siegy22 yes i am using ubuntu server.  I'll have a look at systemd for autostart.

Comment: @fade2black do you still use the described solution? how it goes until now? is it reliable?

Comment: @medBouzid Hi, sorry for late response. Yes it still works, and I am happy with it. However, I strongly recommend you explore systemctl. Lately I have written another service, but it simply loops forever, retrieves a dada from WWW, and stores in DB. systemctl has necessary tools to write robust services.

Comment: @fade2black I will explore systemctl thank you for the recommendation, what I thought about your solution above is that the script itself can stop if its process crashes, maybe systemctl is the best solution in this case like you said :) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use process monitoring tools such as monit, god, eye etc. These tools can check for resque PID and memory usage at time interval specified by you.  You also have options to restart background processes if the memory limit exceeds your specified expectations. Personally, I use eye gem.

Comment: Thanks for for response. I had a look at it. It is not documented at all.  What does it do? How to use? What is logic behind this "monitor" tool? Linux 'top' command is also a monitor tool, so it is not clear what the difference is between the 'top' and this 'tool'. Simply examples are NOT documents. Usually I avoid such 'tools' or monsters like Monit which are usually full of bugs.

Comment: Which gem  are you planning to use?

Comment: I am not going to use any gem yet. But first I want to try God and then Eye. For now, the script I posted works fine.

Comment: @UmeshMalhotra I find it unfortunate that you haven't posted details how you use Eye gem, I would use it but no easy description for it

Answer (score 0):

You could do it much simpler. Start Resque in foreground. When it exits, start it again. No pid files, no monitoring, no sleep.

```rb
require 'logger'

class Restarter
  def initialize(cmd:, logger: Logger.new(STDOUT))
    @cmd = cmd
    @logger = logger
  end

  def start
    loop do
      @logger.info("Starting #{@cmd}")
      system(@cmd)
      @logger.warn("Process exited: #{@cmd}")
    end
  end
end

restarter = Restarter.new(
  cmd: 'cd /var/www/agts-api && (RAILS_ENV=production rake resque:workers QUEUE='*' COUNT='12') 2>&1 | tee -a log/resque.log',
  logger: Logger.new('watch.log', 'daily')
)
restarter.start
```